# Jenkins node launch stuck

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I've a Jenkins node configured on Linux machine which was working fine till last night but today it went offline automatically.

And when tried to launch it stuck with following logs -

```
just before slave <node-name> gets launched ...
executing pre-launch scripts ...
```

I'm unable to find the cause of this issue. Could you please guide me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, machine was not responding. Hence the node went offline. Even after restarting the machine, got same error while launching node.

Hence I deleted existing node and created the same again and it worked.

Comment: For me just renaming it also helped. maybe that makes Jenkins forget some stuck state..

Answer (score 1):

That mean the agent machine is offline, you can check that agent status in Jenkins to find out reason why its offline.

Need to be execute to bring the agent online again.